# Pandas dataframe regex replace not working in new version

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This code used to work in older pandas versions (0.24.2), but throws error in current version (1.3.0): *ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-like to_replace and non-None value*.

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame([['the quick red fox jumps over the lazy dog','red|over'],['red is the color for danger','red']], columns=['text','match'])
a['text'].replace(r'('+a['match']+')', r'<*\1*>', regex=True, inplace=True)

print(a)
```

How can I make it work on  the newer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

```
a['text']=a['text'].replace('('+'|'.join(a['match'].tolist())+')', r'<*\1*>', regex=True)
```

output of `a`:

```
    text                                                  match
0   the quick <*red*> fox jumps <*over*> the lazy dog   red|over
1   <*red*> is the color for danger                      red
```